"Três mil Dólares é suficiente" ou "são suficientes"?
Estão corretas as duas formas?

Você acha que 3.000 Dólares é suficiente para eu passar uma semana em Miami?
Você acha que 3.000 Dólares são suficientes para eu passar uma semana em Miami?

Isso foi tema de uma discussão que presenciei recentemente, onde as duas partes achavam que estavam certas.

Pro meu ouvido, a primeira frase tem alguma omissão, tipo "(ter) $3.000 é suficiente?".

Tudo depende de se você considera 3.000 dólares uma unidade ou não.

Ambos podem estar correctos "Você acha que [a quantia de] 3.000 Dólares é suficiente para eu passar uma semana em Miami?" ou "Você acha que [os copiosos] 3.000 Dólares são suficientes para eu passar uma semana em Miami?"

Resumo: Conservadoramente, o singular é provavelmente o mais indicado, mas eu não rejeitaria o plural como errado.

A especialista em linguística Dad Squarisi afirma:

Se o sujeito dá ideia de preço, peso, medida, valor ou quantidade, o verbo [ser] fica no singular. Não se flexiona. Por isso, diga:

Trinta pontos é suficiente.
Vinte reais era suficiente para pagar o almoço.
Dois quilos é suficiente para chegar ao peso ideal.
R$ 29 mil é suficiente para contratação de assessores de bom nível.


Mas ela faz uma importante ressalva:

Se o numeral estiver antecedido de modificador (artigo, pronome), perde o privilégio. O verbo se torna igual aos demais. Concorda com o sujeito:

Os 28% não são suficientes.
Quaisquer 5 mil reais são suficientes para pagar a viagem.
Uns dois quilos a mais seriam suficientes para ele recuperar o peso.


Pessoalmente, penso que esse é um caso que, como o das diferentes concordâncias aceitáveis em frases como "A maioria das mulheres foi/foram embora", admite certa flexibilidade. Inclusive a própria descrição acima, "Se o sujeito dá ideia de [...] quantidade", parece abrir espaço para a subjetividade na aplicação da regra: se em minha cabeça "3 mil dólares" é um monte de dólares, nota sobre nota, e não meramente uma quantia, o plural pode refletir isso melhor.
E não faltam contraexemplos à prescrição acima. Por exemplo a filóloga Maria Regina Rocha escreve:

Foram suficientes dois minutos para ele compreender tudo.


Por completude, vale mencionar o caso da construção:


3'000 dólares é/são o suficiente.


em que temos "o suficiente", que é uma locução adverbial e, portanto, invariável, i.e., fixa, quer se use "é" ou "são" (1, 2, 3, 4).
Aqui se poderiam aplicar os argumentos e regras gerais de concordância verbal para "ser" (e.g., 5, 6, 7, 8) para determinar a conjugação do verbo, mas a prescrição que (mais) se encontra determina o uso do singular (9, 10):


3'000 dólares é o suficiente.



O blog está muito bem escrito, mas não dá a razão para isso.
